# Handle network configuration sms

Tags: java, android, sms, ota

I want to handle received sms that contains network configurations(OMA OTA). I have already developed android application that catches typical sms from inbox. Network configuration is not a typical sms. How can I get it? What is a Broadcast Action for that?
I was trying this:

```
<receiver android:name="ru.tenet.pdureceiver.SMSReceiver" >
           <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
           </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

As I understood, `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a [solution](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION). The action is:

```
android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED
```

And also there must be a mimeType defined for wap message.
For example:

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.connectivity-wbxml" />
</intent-filter>
```